# Accessing Device camera on Android phone and iPhone using javascript or php or some other language

Tags: php, android, iphone, performance, camera

How can I access device camera from browser using a button on my website on Android phone  and iPhone. I am not sure if its even possible if website is made in PHP
Please help me if someone has solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's rather done through JavaScript, but it's unfortunately not possible for a website to access the camera on a mobile device right now, but things may change soon if the Android/iOS browsers start to provide support for the [HTML5 getUserMedia API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

You may however be able to use a file picker that asks the user to take a photo or select from the gallery (at least on iOS). See https://web.archive.org/web/20130520232826/http://www.aaronlumsden.com/articles/ios6-the-benefits-for-html5-web-app-development/  for more information.

Comment: Yeah that's right, i solved this problem by just adding  <input type="file" > and it solved my problem. :-)

Comment: Actually, i also had figured out doing this using file picker, but my problem starts after photo has been taken. How to show "upload" or "cancel" buttons after photo has been taken using camera. Facebook messenger for android does this correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible right now. Facebook Messenger is a native app though, so it doesn't use any HTML input field

Comment: It's an input field. Handle it like you would any other input field. `<form action="upload-page.php" method="post"><input name="image" type="file" accept="image/*"><input type="submit" value="Upload the file" style="display:none"></form>`

Comment: The method I have been using is to get an app like CloudCam or something similar then just use a url reference to the second server running under the camera app.